# multiple line-plots in gnuplot using C

Tags: c, terminal, gnuplot

For a terminal application written in C I need to plot (in the terminal) two tables as line plots. To do this I use (following e.g. [gnu tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/gnuplot/example/27408/plotting-multiple-data-files))

```
 FILE *gnuplot = popen("gnuplot", "w");
 ...
  fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' u 1:2 t 'data1' w lp lt 0\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
        fprintf(gnuplot,"%f %f \n", x[i] - x[0], y[i]);
    }
fprintf(gnuplot, "\n");
  fprintf(gnuplot, "t 'data2' lt 2\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i) {
        fprintf(gnuplot,"%f %f \n", x[i] - x[0], 0.4*(x[i] - c0)/c1);
    }
    fprintf(gnuplot, "e\n");
    fflush(gnuplot);
```

The problem is that the data is plotted as one data block instead of two different ones. I expected to have a separation by using the line

```
fprintf(gnuplot, "t 'data2' lt 2\n");
```

which seems not to be the case. What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do the following. Each inline data has to be terminated by an `e`.
In gnuplot console it would be:

```
plot '-' u 1:2 t 'data1' w lp lt 0, '' u 1:2 t 'data2' lt 2
 1  0.1
 2  0.2
 3  0.3
 4  0.4
e
11  0.5
12  0.6
13  0.7
14  0.8
e
```

Check `help inline data` and `help special-filenames`.
Although, to my opinion it is a bit confusing and suitable examples are missing. Maybe you can find them elsewhere.